# TypeError: Cannot set property X of #<Object> which has only a getter. Ошибка при запуске кода сделанным webpack`ом

Tags: javascript, webpack

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property global_timeout of # which has only a getter - вылазит вот такая ошибка и так же eslint выдает такое 'global_timeout' is read-only.eslintno-import-assign. В документации eslint`а на счет этоq ошибки не понятно что это и предлагаемый фикс не работает

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "common.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "js",
    "javascript",
    "webpack"
  ],
  "author": "jhartum",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.52.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-concat-plugin": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "exports-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "imports-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "merge-files-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.2",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/check.js'],
  // devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundlse.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
  }
```

check.js

```
import {globalTimeout} from './entry.js';

export var global_timeout;

console.log('start global timeout');

globalTimeout();
```

entry.js

```
import {global_timeout} from './check.js';
    
export async function globalTimeout() {
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    global_timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      reject('Global timer timed out after 4000 ms');
    }, 4000);
  });
}
```

Comment: Конфигурации по сути нет, и бабель вероятно транспайлит импорты по-умолчанию... Что ты хочешь получить в итоге - модули/бандл? если модули, то оставить es-импорты или заменять их? если бандл (вероятнее, судя по конфигу вебпака), то почему нет соотв. конфига бейбла и используются умолчания? Всю эту информацию надо бы дописать в вoпрос.

Comment: Суть проблемы похоже в том что на переэкспорты транспайлятся не так как ожидается. Но здесь нет указания целей `babel-loader`'у, и при том что в вебпаке по-умолчанию целевая платформа `'web'` - _«When no targets are specified: **Babel will assume you are targeting the oldest browsers possible.** For example, @babel/preset-env **will transform all ES2015-ES2020 code to be ES5 compatible**.»_ Надо "объяснить" транспайлеру чего ты хочешь, ведь сам он не угадает...

Comment: Еще можно попробовать работать со свойством `window` (вместо объявления глобальной переменной через `var`), чтобы не пробрасывать переэкспортом переменную - в плане кода, смысл будет одинаков, но меньше сложностей на транспайле. Это если уж совсем не хочется работать в объектном стиле и иметь общую зависимость вместо переэкспорта.

Comment: https://2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html#es6-modules-export-immutable-bindings
export отдаёт вам не переменную, а «неизменяемую связь» с переменной в модуле. Её нельзя переприсвоить снаружи

Comment: @yar85 экспорты как раз транспайлятся по спецификации. `import { a } from 'module'; a = 42;` даёт ошибку

Comment: @AlexeyTen, _«экспорты как раз транспайлятся по спецификации»_ - тогда почему в документации babel (см. цитату выше) написано что без указания целей транспайл с env-пресетом выполняется в ES5, доки врут? Или ты имел в виду что у параметров целей бейбла есть какие-то fallback значения которые я не нашел в доках?

Comment: Я имею в виду, что по спеке попытка присвоения значение переменной полученной через import это ошибка. И babel сделал так что это дейстивительно ошибка. А ES5 это всего-лишь указание какой JS поддерживается на целевой платформе.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, с ошибкой-то понятно, но это касается **нативных** импортов, а вот **транспайл** es-модулей вполне может делать переменную изменяемой (видимо, babel так не делает сознательно: для соответствия стандартному поведению - но все же, есть вероятность что это как-то можно настроить... и если я верно понимаю вoпрос, он как раз в "настройте мне чтобы это работало", т.к. конфиги у ТСа почти пустые и отсутствует вопрос "почему").

Comment: Ну, самое простое, это не пытаться сломать стандартное поведение, а заэкспортить объект и сохранять данные в свойства объекта. Либо вообще заэкспортить отдельную функцию которая будет менять эту переменную (как в примере по ссылке выше)